# C++ IDE to see assembly generated before/after inlining?

Tags: c++, ide, x86, assembly

I am trying to illustrate the effects of inlining a function on a basic C++ example. I have been doing this using Visual Studio 2012 but the problem is when I go to look at the inlined code the release-mode doesn't allow me to see the assembly in the Disassembly window. When I output the assembly file the assembly is really not readable (and doesnt look vaguely correct).

I was wondering either somebody knows a solution to the Visual Studio Disassembly release mode problem, or is there another idea where I could see the inlined assembly very easily (like the VS Disassembly window in debug mode).

Comment: Code generated by the optimizer rarely looks correct.  It requires a trained eye that looks at *many* examples to see the pattern.  Looking at the disassembly is always possible, you are just not doing it right if you think you can't.  Another "trained eye" aspect perhaps.

Comment: In the release mode enable Debug Info, it doesnt slow down the code, only make the file somewhat bigger. Inline functions often disappear totally (especially for member accessing). Then as already said it's a question of trained eye. Since the code works the assembly is correct. BTW why do you need to see the disassembled code in release mode? Use the Debug build.